# Why child theme stylesheet takes long time to update?

Tags: css

I don't face this problem with every site I work on! But sometimes, it happen. The problem whenever I add some style to the stylesheet of child theme. It doesn't show the effects immediately, they do but take 1-2 hours for update.

Can anyone please tell me; I'm missing something or making any error. And is this happen to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers cache stylesheets to save bandwidth. In most browsers you can hold CTRL (or CMD on a mac) and click the refresh button to force it to re-download.

In Chrome, if you have the Inspector Tools open, then you can right-click the refresh button and it will show you 3 options, "Reload", "Hard Reload", and "Empty Cache and Hard Reload."

You may also have a site caching plugin installed which would need to be cleared using its controls. In this case it would not be the browser caching the .css file, but rather the server sending the cached file.